# Read values from named ranges with openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

How can I read values from named ranges in Excel with openpyxl?

I've found the sourcecode at http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/names/named_range.html but I can't figure out how to use it properly.

Answer (score 11):

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_name) 
rng = wb.get_named_range(name_of_range).destinations[0]
sheet = rng[0]
address = rng[1].replace('$','')
val = sheet[address].value
```

Comment: since Openpyxl 2.41 `get_named_range` was deprecated, and `destinations` now iterator -> you can use
`list(wb.defined_names['rangename'].destinations)[0][1].replace('$','')`

Comment: `wb.defined_names['Scenarios'].destinations` returns a generator, but how can it be used? Converting to list returns an empty list.