# Using Excel named ranges in Python with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

How do I loop through the cells in an Excel named range/defined name and set each cell value within the named range using openpyxl with Python 2.7?

I found the following, but have not managed to get it to work for printing and setting the values of individual cells within the named range.

[Read values from named ranges with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896209/read-values-from-named-ranges-with-openpyxl)

Here's my code so far, I have put in comments where I am looking to make the changes. Thanks in anticipation.

```
    #accessing a named range called 'metrics' 
    namedRange = loadedIndividualFile.defined_names['metrics']

    #obtaining a generator of (worksheet title, cell range) tuples
    generator = namedRange.destinations

    #looping through the generator and getting worksheet title, cell range

    cells = []
    for worksheetTitle, cellRange in generator:
        individualWorksheet = loadedIndividualFile[worksheetTitle]

        #==============================
        #How do I set cell values here?
        # I am looking to print and change each cell value within the defined name range
        #==============================

        print cellRange
        print worksheetTitle
        #theWorksheet = workbook[worksheetTitle]
        #cell = theWorksheet[cellRange]
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Extracting individual cell values, but I have resolved it now and will post the solution in case anyone else ever has the same issue. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to resolve it. Perhaps the following will be useful to someone else who is looking to access the values of each cell in a defined name or named range using openpyxl.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('filename.xlsx') 
#getting the address 
address = list(wb.defined_names['metrics'].destinations)

#removing the $ from the address
for sheetname, cellAddress in address:
    cellAddress = cellAddress.replace('$','')

#looping through each cell address, extracting it from the tuple and printing it out     
worksheet = wb[sheetname]
for i in range(0,len(worksheet[cellAddress])):
    for item in worksheet[cellAddress][i]:
        print item.value`
```

Comment: Should the bottom third be indented?

Comment: This just helped me in 2020. Thanks for answering your own question!