# How do I set user-level permissions on Excel ranges i.e. 'Allow Users to Edit Ranges' with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openxml, openpyxl

Using openpyxl and Python 3.6, I'm trying to set [user-level permissions on certain ranges](http://amazingexcel.com/allow-user-to-edit-a-specific-range-cells-in-protected-sheet/) in a worksheet which would allow the user to edit it (only sort/filter in my case) even when the sheet is locked.

This screenshot shows how you'd do this manually in Excel 2016, via *Review -> Allow Users to Edit Ranges*:

[image: Screenshot from Excel 2016]

I looked into [Named Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896209/read-values-from-named-ranges-with-openpyxl) / [Defined Names](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/defined_names.html), but to no avail. Here are source links to [`worksheet`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/0f8537998f95c9d8d44913c2edb367516b799d4a/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [`protection`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/0f8537998f95c9d8d44913c2edb367516b799d4a/openpyxl/worksheet/protection.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with openpyxl (2.4 & 2.5). Support for `protectedRanges` (the element in the specification) could be added in a future version of the library.